# Python Can't Import Modules

Tags: python, pip

I have installed multiple modules using pip but I can't access any of them. I can check and see that the modules are installed using `pip list`, but when I try to access them in python I just get `ModuleNotFoundError` no matter what. I can't find any help anywhere online and honestly just want to stop learning python because I have so many problems like this every day.
[image]

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which environment manager (`conda`, `pipenv`, ...) are you using? What did you try so far?

Comment: So how are you trying to import them? Please add example code to your question of how you're trying to import the modules and what the exact error is.

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be two different locations python was installed to. Problem solved by moving f2py.exe to the proper location and setting the proper PATH locations.

Comment: as a rule of thumb to enjoy coding with python and make your dev env match the prod env, always use virtual environments and never the system's python.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give up! Python is great. I think you've installed the modules in an environment which might not be the same your code uses at runtime.

At the top of your code try to add:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You might notice that your code uses another location.

Comment: It seems like the modules are being installed to the directory 'appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages' when maybe they should be installing to 'AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages'. How can I change the directory that pip installs to?